# window.top.location.href is not working in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, window

window.top.location href is not working on native and hybrid apps. It is working on all browsers and mobile browser even. Please suggest any modifications to be done. Thanks in advance for your reply

Comment: var getRedirectUrl = function(){ return "https://exampleurl.com";}  var redirectToMainPAge = function(){ $window.top.location.href = getRedirectUrl(); return false; }  ... This is the code snippet for your reference . on calling redirectToMainPAge, it is showing a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

Android uses `document.location` whereas iOS supports `window.location.replace` therefore `window.top.location.href` you are using is not working.

Comment: hi @Rhadamanthys, window.location.replace will override the location of current window but this is not something like a redirected window being opened.